# omit transactions for specific methods in spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, debugging, spring-transactions

I'm using the @Transactional annotation for my entire Dao class with spring and hibernate.  Everything works great, it's just that I would like to omit the behaviour for a few non database related methods in my Dao.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.4/reference/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations

Every time I step into these methods during a debugging session, I always get to JdkDynamicAopProxy.class which is super annoying.

Is there any way to omit transactional for specific methods? Or at least fix this annoying debugging behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring you can put the `@Transactional` annotation on only the methods you want to make transactional, instead of putting it at the class level.

Otherwise perhaps consider extracting those specific non-transactional methods into a separate class?

Comment: I seem to remember having issues when the annotation wasnt applied to the whole class, but I can try again. Thanks!